# Read and change project properties "Start external program" and "command line arguments"

Tags: c#, vspackage

[image]

I'm trying to read (and change) the project properties "Start external program" and "Command line arguments" of a VisualStudio 2013 project within a VSPackage. The code I wrote so far looks like:

```
var dte = GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
if (dte == null)
    return;

var sb = (SolutionBuild2)dte.Solution.SolutionBuild;
var projectNames = sb.StartupProjects as Array;
if (projectNames == null || projectNames.Length == 0)
  return;

var project = dte.Solution.Item(projectNames.GetValue(0));
var config = project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
```

But I can't find the two spcific properties neither in the `project` nor in the `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EnvDTE.Configuration class has a Properties collection that has your desired values:

config.Properties.Item("StartProgram").Value

config.Properties.Item("StartArguments").Value

FWIW, the VSLangProj.dll assembly has a [VSLangProj.ProjectConfigurationProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.projectconfigurationproperties_properties.aspx) class with the property names that you can expect in the config.Properties collection.